# Tinymce editor create plugin async problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I development accordion menu plugin. 
I make  once begin popup form set accordion menu piece after set accordion menu content.When the specified number of forms are processed, I want to process the data and transfer it to the editor. I do not want to process all the forms to the editor.
Accordion.js code 
https://gist.github.com/ismailaf/f59b95720904cab5a8e2c84d1e774624
how do i use async here?